# Add dynamic styling to received data Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular8

I want to add some css styling to highlight each text like:
[image]

I do not want any cross button and I don't want to give user any option to add tags. I am receiving data from RESTful api in Angular 8 as text separated by , (comma) and I am displaying data as text. It looks like a paragraph. I want to replace each text sentence like this by splitting it on , (comma).

TS code:

```
this.user.data = response.Items;
for (let i = 0; i <= this.user.data.length; i++){
     this.splitString[i] = this.user.data[i].abc.split(',');
     this.finalSplittedString = [...this.splitString[i]];
 }
```

I am receiving an array of object and I am storing it in `user.data` Now I am splitting the string on object parameter `abc`.
JSON OBJECT

```
[{"names":"Hello","abc":"abcdef,ghijk,lmnop"},{"names":"World","abc":"qrstuv,wxyz"}]
```

I want to split the `ABC` and write them as shown in image below. Also, they should be displayed in correct table row.

HTML Code

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="abc">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ABC </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="addTag"> {{element.abc}}</td>
        </ng-container>
```

How can I bind the new splitted sting here?

Answer (score 0):

The key point is to use `split(",")` function to convert a string into array, so that you can display it using `*ngFor` in html

I have created an example for you:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-getting-started-xpndxn?file=src/app/product-list/product-list.component.ts

Comment: this looks good. I will check it out actually my database is down lol :D

Comment: Kelvin I tried to implement this solution but my logic is little more complex.

Comment: I am editing my code and if you can help me fix it, I will upvote this answer. This is close to what I am looking at.

Answer (score 0):

For ex, in your TS file you have this-

```
export class ChipsOverviewExample {

  availableColors:string[];
  sentence:string;
  constructor(){
    this.sentence="Green,red,pink";
    this.availableColors=this.sentence.split(',');

  }
  
}
```

In your HTML you can use basic chips-

```
<mat-chip-list aria-label="Fish selection">
 <mat-chip class="chips" *ngFor="let chip of availableColors" >
    {{chip}}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

And in your CSS, you can style accordingly-

```
.chips{
  background-color: chocolate;
}
```

Comment: this did not work for me. Actually I need it on mat-table and so when I define matcellDef it gives weird errors

Comment: Ohh there was no mention of a table when i saw this question. I believe you edited. Will try to do the way you want.